# listview for a single row?

Tags: android

I've got an application which displays a field that can have multiple entries but I only wish to show the first entry and then give the user the option to expand that to display all items. I was thinking of making this a listview but once it's expanded I want it to retain the expansion.

the text field in question is part of a viewpager not a view on it's own.

Anyone got any good ideas or advice? 
Thanks, m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ExpandableListView` with single item group.

Comment: Thanks, would I be able to set that up in code quickly in the instantiateitem method of the viewpageradapter?